# How do I move a bunch of files using a Move MSBuild task and a wildcard?

Tags: msbuild

I have a folder with files that have names starting with `App_Web_` and ending with `.dll`. I don't know what's in between those parts and I don't know the number of files. I need MSBuild to move those files into another folder.

So I composed this:

```
<Move
    SourceFiles="c:\source\App_Web_*.dll"
    DestinationFolder="c:\target"
/>
```

but when the target runs I get the following output:

```
error MSB3680: The source file "c:\source\App_Web_*.dll" does not exist.
```

The files are definitely there.

What am I doing wrong? How do I have the files moved?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot use regular expression directly in task parameters. You need to create an item containing list of files to move and pass its content to the task:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToMove Include="c:\source\App_Web_*.dll"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

MSBuild will expand regular expression before passing it to the task executor. So later in some target you may invoke `Move` task:

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <Move
        SourceFiles="@(FilesToMove)"
        DestinationFolder="C:\target"
    />
</Target>
```

Comment: I get `error : Error initializing task Move: Not registered task Move`

Comment: "You cannot use regular expression directly in task parameters" - Any perticular reason why it is not possible.