# Xamarin forms, Copy forms folder to platforms specific project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/) link to implement `webkit` to my app, in sample of the article, they copied `index.html` file inside both Android and iOS platforms folders (iOS: `/Content/index.html`, Android: `/Assets/Content/index.html`), my project is more complicated and has about 2000 files and many folders related to web side (instead of that single `index.html` file), how can I place my web side files into `Xamarin.Forms` main project folder and in compile time, they be copied to their platform specific folder? For android it seems that they should be in `Asset` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MSBuild` - [FilesToMove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746353/7292772).

Also you will need to update your android and iOS project files to include them as resource or assets. For e.g:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <!-- your normal project content -->
   <Content Include="MainActivity.cs" />

   <!-- your static content you like to publish -->
   <AndroidResource Include="web\**\*.*"  />
</ItemGroup>
```