# How to delete a list of files with MSBuild Delete task without using ItemsGroup

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I know, a list of files can be deleted using MSBuild Delete task with the help of `<ItemsGroup>`. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482551/3197387). However is there a way to do the same without using the .

Basically can delete task do something similar to `<Exec Command="del /f /q *.pdp"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you want is something like:

```
<Target Name="TestDelete" AfterTargets="xxx">
    <Delete Files="$(Outputpath)*.pdb"/>
</Target>
```

But as I know the wildcard is not recognized in **msbuild task parameters**.

So the answer is negative I'm afraid. I recommend you use wildcard in Items to refer to the list of files.

Check [MSBuild Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#use-wildcards-to-specify-items) and [MSBuild Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-tasks?view=vs-2019).In official document, only Items is clearly stated that it supports for wildcards.

Also, you can check this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744826/how-do-i-move-a-bunch-of-files-using-a-move-msbuild-task-and-a-wildcard).

**Update:**

Actually not sure the real reason of the particular design. I've just read the [Task Writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing?view=vs-2019) document. And write a simple MyDelete task to research.

```
public class MyDelete:Task
    {
        [Required]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            // Log a high-importance comment
            Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High,
                "MyDelete Task has delete files: \"" + MyProperty + "\".");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then I add the script below into project file:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyMessage.MyDelete"
        AssemblyFile="MyDelete.dll"/>

  <Target Name="MyTarget" AfterTargets="build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyItem Include="$(Outputpath)*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MyDelete MyProperty="$(Outputpath)*.*"/>
    <MyDelete MyProperty="@(MyItem)"/>
  </Target>
```

The build output should be like:
[image]

My guess is for most tasks, the property is string, so the input which contains a wildcard is a string variable "path*.*", which can't be recognized by the code of the task **directly**.

But for Item, according to document：Item types are named lists of items that can be used as parameters for tasks. So the input is string like "xxx;xxx;xxx..." which perform well.

My update is just to make a deep research, hard to answer the particular reason about the design. I think if you do want to know the design reason, you may need to ask some help from who supports the product by [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues).

Comment: Any particular reason why it is designed this way?

Comment: @Sisir Hi friend, please check if my update helps. And if my answer is helpful to resolve the question in your original post, you could consider marking it as answer :(  If you want further details about why the product team designed it this way, I suggest you could open a new thread on [Github\Msbuild](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues) to get info from product team.